# Adding Items the Ion-List (Ionic)

Tags: html, list, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have this in my html page:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list></ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I want to add items to this list from my .ts file. How do I do such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rendering HTML on .ts is not a good option, you should add an Array/Observable on .ts and 
render it using ngFor

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let term of yourArray;">
        <p>{{term}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

.ts Code will be,

```
yourArray = ['first','second'];
```

Comment: If I add items to yourArray later during the program, do I have to re-renderfor the items to show up on the list?

Comment: no need to do, it uses two way databinding so it will be rendered automatically

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "adding ion-items to my **.ts** file"? You are supposed to add *ion-items* to your *ion-list* in the **.html** file.

Try the following:

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item>
        My first item in this list
     </ion-item>

     <ion-item>
       My second item in this list
     </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Please [refer to the documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/item/Item/#usage) in order to view a full example of **ion-items** inside **ion-lists.**

Comment: I want to add these items from the ts file

Comment: Please check the link of the official documentation I have refered to. There are simple examples for displaying items from variables in your **.ts** file.